# Data attributes in wordpress wp_register_script and pagespeed

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I would like to load the most of my javascripts async to speed up the rendering. Sadly defer is breaking a lot of parts of my wordpress website and i need to exclude it from async load. One file of my theme is using the code

```
    wp_register_script( 'tie-masonry',      get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/isotope.js',            array( 'jquery' ),  false, true );
```

Pagespeed is needing the attribute data-pagespeed-no-defer
Like `<script data-pagespeed-no-defer>...</script>` to exclude it.

Is it possible to add this attribute to the wp_register_script, or do i need to exclude it from the php file and insert it by hand into the webpage?

Comment: This can help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111882/101048

Comment: Thanks. But this looks extreme complicated, would it not be faster with less querys to included the script just in the head with the attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since 4.1.0 there is a filter hook 'script_loader_tag', which is perfect for this task.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'my_script_loader_tag', 10 ,2 );
function my_script_loader_tag( $tag, $handle ){
    if ( $handle == 'tie-masonry' ) {
        return str_replace( '<script', '<script data-pagespeed-no-defer', $tag );
    }
    return $tag;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, one question if i use a lot of this hooks, will this have a high impact of the load time?

Comment: No worry. This is just a simple filter hook. Have a look on the source code [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/do_item/) Line 356